# CI session BLOB size

Tags: codeigniter, session, blob

I plan to store quite a few pieces of data about my users in CI session. As we know it is stored in a blob.

My question is, anyone could tell me, what size can BLOB be, before I should be getting worried about impact on performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got 65535 characters.
Preformance really depends on your server, how many queries you use etc.
Why do you need to store it in the session?

Comment: Well I dont 'need' to store it in the session per say. I just thought that it would be my best option. I could do cookie, but it is type of information I dont want user to be able to tamper with. I could do separate DB table.. but then again, I thought if CI session is making the DB query already, why not just use that Db call instead of making another one. Anyway, 65535 chars sounds like more than I ever will need.... Thanks :)

Comment: OK. But you do need the information on every single request, right? If so, then storing it in the session could be a smart move, it does save you 1 extra query. 65535 characters is a lot of space.The encoding makes it bigger than the actual data that you're storing. Perhaps you could use the Benchmarking class to see what works faster.